# Install4j 8.x customization

Tags: install4j

Install4j is a great installer to work with. But i found some limitation for it and also it works differently on different platform OS.Right now i am working on Windows OS. Below are my queries .Please suggest some good solution.

1)I want to customize the install4j window. By default it corner shaped, i want it to be round edged at corners. How can i customize this window ie. changing shapes, changing the opacity, color, etc.

2)In directory chooser can we customize the the "Browse" button. I want to add image to the button matching to our theme.Is there any way to do that?

3)When i disable the "minimize" option for installer ,it is not clickable but still shows the disable icon.Can we make it disappear that?It works on CentOS but on windows it still shows the icon.

4)Can we customize title bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In install4j 8.x, no window customizations are supported and it is also not possible to set an icon for the file chooser button.